# Knockout.JS Bindinghandlers moment.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, momentjs

I want to format my knockoutjs binded dates with moment.js. What is wrong with my code?

```
        var modelNots;
        function NotsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.msgs = ko.observableArray();     
        }
        modelNots = new NotsViewModel();
        var thediv=$("#notSection")[0];
        ko.applyBindings(modelNots, thediv );

        ko.bindingHandlers.Date = {
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                var date = moment(value());
                var strDate = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                $(element).text(strDate);
            }
        };
```

Html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: msgs">
   <div data-bind="text:Date"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a new data binder in Knockout you are creating a new prefix, so your html should look like this (assuming each msgs element has a "value" property:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: msgs">
   <div data-bind="Date: value"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i changed the html to `<div data-bind="bDate:Date"></div>`and js to `   ko.bindingHandlers.bDate = {...` but nothing is binded

Comment: maybe this has to do with it that i have the model binded to a node?

Comment: In your code above you have "msgs" as an observable array, but you don't actually add anything to it. Without any items in the array there is nothing TO render.

Comment: i add the values in another place. msgs has values. that is not the problem.

Comment: moment.js seems to be the problem. date format is: 2013-02-27T11:19:00.853

Comment: You may also need an "init" for your binding handler as well.

Comment: How do you get this thing to work? We are doing the exact same thing with update and init inside the binding handler, but still couldn't get it to work!